# How do I put a field inside a span block?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Good day!

There is a script to check the validity of the field, it produces an error message in the field:

```
<span class="input__error" id="error-for-phone">Wrong number</span>

var message = field.form.querySelector('.input__error#error-for-' + id);

if (!message) {
    message = document.createElement('span');
    message.className = 'input__error';
    message.id = 'error-for-' + id;

    // If the field is a radio button or checkbox, insert error after the label
    var label;
    if (field.type === 'radio' || field.type === 'checkbox') {
        label = field.form.querySelector('label[for="' + id + '"]') || field.parentNode;
        if (label) {
            label.parentNode.insertBefore(message, label.nextSibling);
        }
    }
    // В противном случае вставьте его после поля
    if (!label) {
        field.parentNode.insertBefore(message, field.nextSibling);
    }
}
```

In the template there is a block:

```
<span class="input__text">
     <span class="input__label">Phone number</span> 
     Example: <span class="input__error">Wrong number</span> 
</span>
```

Tell me please how to force the field with an error is displayed inside the block as indicated in the example?

At the moment the field is shown on top of the required block.

Thank you.

Comment: Any idea of using Bootstrap and similar libraries? It offers wide range of styling, one of which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I do not think that for such a simple task it is necessary to use Bootstrap...

Comment: Oh, I see. You were not asked to write the Bootstrap library. Just linking it with your html offers the feature you are looking at in a snap of fingers without explicit JavaScript functions.

Comment: This is not the whole script, only part of the code, the full script is here https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/ But it prints the error information at the bottom of the input field and needs to be printed as indicated in the example inside the span

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dejMzZ. Is this what you are looking at?